# deployd and mongodb in PROAngularJS test project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, deployd

This is my first experience with MongoDB and Deployd. I installed MongoDB and Deployd. Everything seems to be ok but when I run from the command line I get this result

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\deployd\sportsstore>dpd --mongod 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe' -p 5500

C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\deployd\node_modules\fs-extra\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:21
  chdir.call(process, d)
        ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir

    at Error (native)
    at process.chdir
```

I'm running Node server.js and Mongod.exe. I do not know why, but it does not help.

**How do I solve this problem?**

Comment: Can you correct the formatting of the error message please or attach a screenshot?

Comment: @der_michael [pic to bug](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BypalRqfNSrPTEtfczdWX1VXNjA) add to the environment variable 'path' to mongoDB. did not help (((